# How do I get all changes of several files of two changessets in tfs or two branches in git?

Tags: git, tfs

So I have a basic version of my code in a changeset and also in a git branch. But now I want all the changes which I did between these two changessets or two branches in one file.

As an example i have a index.html file, which looks in the master branch similar like this

```
<a>Hello World</a>
```

and then I have index2.html with this content

```
<i>Hello</i>
```

Now several weeks later I added/changed some code (index.html):

```
<a>Hello World! (Test)</a>
<b>Test</b>
```

And i also added some code to the index2.html file.

```
<i>Hello World<i>
```

Now I want all the changes in a text file, something like this:

```
--index.html    
<a>Hello World! (Test)</a>
<b>Test</b>
--index2.html
<i>Hello World</i>
```

But the problem is that I can do this for one or two files manually but in my project I have  hundreds of files. The changes of these files should be all in the same text file visible. Is this possilbe with tfs or git?

Comment: "TFS" is a devops platform that supports two types of version control: Git and TFVC. Are you talking about a Git repo hosted in TFS, or are you talking about a TFVC repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's the length of the output which makes it impractical to you, why not just send it (`>`) to a text file :

```
git diff --pretty=format:"" branch1 branch2 > path/to/diff_file.txt
```

(here `--pretty=format:""` suppresses all commit info to leave only code diffs.)